# Cisco IOS bandwidth monitoring

Tags: networking, cisco

I was wondering if there was a way somewhat like show ip flow top-talkers to show highest bandwidth use. Now show ip flow top-talkers is good but I want to know in a bytes/sec average over the past however long, not the flow transfer that is reported in top-talkers.

Comment: Have you looked at NetFlow? http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6601/products_ios_protocol_group_home.html

Answer (score 0):

The interface statistics on 'sh int' and 'sh ip int' have some of what you want. The best thing to do is to set up something like opsview to graph your interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Netflow should be able to show all the information that you require and more, it will need setting up on the router and then pointing towards a Netflow collector.

There are a few of these collectors/analysers around, the paid are generally better, however I am sure you will find a suitable free version.